# Do sum on a data table

Tags: c#, datatable

I have `DTgraph` data table and I want to group the rows on `Campaign` column and do sum for the `Inb.ServiceLevel` column.

I tried this:

```
var result = from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
             select new
             {
                 TeamID = grp.Key,
                 MemberCount = grp.Count(),
                 s = grp.Sum(s => s."Inb.ServiceLevel")
             };
```

everthing is working fine except the last line in code which is `s = grp.Sum(s => s."Inb.ServiceLevel")` it gives me complie error.

What should have I done to make the sum please?

#### Edit

The complie error is `Identifier expected` . It shows on `Ibn.ServiceLevel`

Comment: @Hatsjoem no I will try it and update you

Comment: @Steve the complie error is `Identifier expected` . It shows on `Ibn.ServiceLevel`

Comment: You should reference that field with "[Inb.ServiceLevel]"

Comment: @Steve I just tried that and I got `Identifier expected` again

Comment: Is the `Ibn.ServiceLevel` a column name or something like navigation?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it is a column

Comment: Try this. `s = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("Inb.ServiceLevel"))` Set the `Field<T>` proper type property.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it is a float value in string format. is it possible to change it to tostring() ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan check pelase

Comment: @Steve could you help ? the HamletHakobyan comment seen to be help, I just want to change the string to float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = grp.Sum(s => float.Parse(s.Field<string>("Inb.ServiceLevel")))
```

But by using float you can lose precision.
To be sure the conversion no fall you can use `float.TryParse`'

Comment: I got this `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.` it seems it is decimal not string. right?

Comment: I changed the string with decimal and removed the float parsing and it works :) thanks

Comment: Great. From your word I understand that it is string.

Answer (score 1):

Use Field instead, I am assuming Inb.ServiceLevel is of type int

```
var result = from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
                     group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         TeamID = grp.Key,
                         MemberCount = grp.Count(),
                         s = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("Inb.ServiceLevel"))
                     };
```

Comment: the `Inb.ServiceLevel` is a string type. I mean it is float but written in string format. got me ?